# Two count request with double where and from in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of two values "1" and "2" in the "ticket" column, but I get an error when I add another line from "where" and "from".

"ticket" is a column, "tickets" is a table.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(ticket) as child FROM tickets WHERE ticket = 1,
COUNT(ticket) as adult FROM tickets WHERE ticket = 2
GROUP by ticket
```

Comment: Aside from subqueries, which these are not, a query may have only one FROM and one WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(if(ticket = 1,1,NULL)) as child,
COUNT(if(ticket = 2,1,NULL)) as adult FROM tickets where ticket in (1,2)
GROUP by ticket
```

or

```
SELECT 
sum(if(ticket = 1,1,0)) as child,
sum(if(ticket = 2,1,0)) as adult FROM tickets where ticket in (1,2)
GROUP by ticket
```

try like this

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(t.ticket = 1) as t1,
       SUM(t.ticket = 2) as t2
FROM tickets t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for conditional aggregation, like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(ticket=1, 1, NULL) AS child
   , COUNT(IF(ticket=2, 1, NULL)) AS adult
FROM tickets
;
```

`COUNT` only counts non-null values.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is syntactically invalid, try this one:

```
   Select count(*)
        , ticket
     from tickets
    where ticket In (1,2)
 Group by ticket
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and let me know in case of any queries.

```
SELECT SUM(ticket = 1) as t1,
       SUM(ticket = 2) as t2
FROM tickets
group by tickets;
```